# DataContext is null in Caliburn.Micro [WPF MVVM]

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro, datacontext

I've read that Caliburn Micro automatically set the DataContext to the viewmodel in viewmodel-first, but when I try to get it from the code-behind of my view, it always returns null, even in my ShellView. (I set up Caliburn Micro following the documentation.)
Do I miss something ?

Comment: In your Code-behind try to get this way     (DataContext as ViewModel).

Comment: I tried already, but it doesn't change a thing.

Comment: you should read more on the naming conventions of Caliburn Micro https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/naming-conventions

Comment: Since my view is correctly displayed and the bindings work just fine, I don't think the names are the issue there.

Comment: can't do much to help with no code. github link or post bootstrap code and what you are attempting?